# How to get the default value of radio button from database?

Tags: forms

I have **5 check-box**. For each check-box, **5 radio buttons get generated.** These radios value get saved to **database**. Now what I want is, when I select check-box, and if the selected check-box has some database value already saved in database, **that radio button should show saved database value**, mean to say, it should be shown **selected**.
5 check-box are like:
1. **A**
2. **B**
3. **C**
4. **D**
5. **C**

All check-box has radio options like:
**Male** or **Female**

If(say) I choose "**Male**" for "**A**" and submit my form. when I again go to that form and choose "**A**", "male" radio button should be shown selected.

*some code implementation:*

```
foreach ($check-box-options as $key => $value) {

        $form['radio_'.$key] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios',
            '#title' => t('abc'),
            '#options' => $filter_radio_options,
            '#default_value'=> ???,
            '#states' => array(
                'visible' => array(
                    ':input[name="filter_criteria_options['.$key.']"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
                ),
            ),
        );
}
```

`$check-box-options` is an array of check-box *A,B,C,D,E*. For each check-box, I have radios.

```
$serialized = unserialize($radio_buttons_database_values);
```

`$serialized` contains all selected radio button values. If I replace `$check-box-options` with `$serialized`, I got **correct radio button selected** as **default**, but if I loop `$serialized` as **nested** inside `$check-box-options`, it is throwing *last selected value* from database for every check-box. I am not getting the exact problem with my code or approach.

Can anyone please help me understanding the exact problem behind this?

Comment: Have you tried `variable_get()`? Can we see how you save these values? Is it a settings form? Is it a node?

Answer (score 4):

As the radios are separate field in itself, default value should be as easy as follow

```
foreach ($check-box-options as $key => $value) {
        //A. A function to query database to get default value
        $default_value = _my_module_helper_get_default_radio_option($key);

        //B. Or if its a system setting form, all values are inside the variables, in that case all you have to do is variable_get()
        $default_value = variable_get('radio_'.$key);

        // Depending on form type use option A or B.

        $form['radio_'.$key] = array(
            '#type' => 'radios',
            '#title' => t('abc'),
            '#options' => $filter_radio_options,
            '#default_value'=> $default_value,
            '#states' => array(
                'visible' => array(
                    ':input[name="filter_criteria_options['.$key.']"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
                ),
            ),
        );
}

// In case option A is what you needed.
function _my_module_helper_get_default_radio_option($key) {
  return db_select('your_table','yt')
         ->fields('yt',array('field_name'))
         ->condition('yt.field_is',$key,'=')
         ->exectue()
         ->fetchField();

 }
```

Comment: `function _my_module_helper_get_default_radio_option($key) {
  $get_defaults =  db_select('your_table','yt')
                ->fields('yt',array('field_name'))
                ->condition('yt.field_is',$key,'=')
                ->exectue()
                ->fetchField();
  return unserialize($get_defaults);

 }` can I write this function this way? Will this also work? @Arpitr

Comment: if you are serializing the values before saving it to database, then yes. But I don't see a need for serializing at all. So the above function expects each radio field will have a field name and its value as an option in database, the reason we are doing a query inside a loop.

Comment: and can you explain `->condition('yt.field_is',$key,'=')`? what should be `field_is` here?

Comment: that was an example, should be replaced with the column name in your database table for holding radio field names